# Monitor/list all/ajax requests in RAD Studio TWebBrowser

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, rad, twebbrowser

Searched the topic over a day (my Delphi/RAD is a little rusty) and all in vain, so asking here.

I'm putting an FMX.WebBrowser.TWebBrowser control and navigate to a page. It works OK.

What is needed is a list of all calls made by the web browser for the complete loading of the page - JS/CSS/images/AJAX - like the Network tab in FireBug works.

Please, advise!

Best regards,
Ilia.

Comment: Use a HTTP proxy such as Fiddler2

Comment: @mjn42 Thank you, I've searched their website and I happen to know the company, but could not find any Firemonkey/RAD Studio related topics or products. I need this monitoring inside the my Android application, so the app could perform further actions, based on the results. Please, elaborate!